# SQL Error: ambiguous column nameor syntax error

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Tried to change my code many times, need help with these errors, please!
**Result: ambiguous column name: main.Guides.Guide_ID**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Guides 
INNER JOIN Guides ON Guides_Countries.Guide_ID = Guides_Countries.Guide_ID
INNER JOIN Countries ON Countries.Country_ID = Guides_Countries.Country_ID
INNER JOIN Guides_Languages ON Guides.Guide_ID = Guides_Languages.Guide_ID
INNER JOIN Languages ON Languages.Language_ID = Guides_Languages.Language_ID
WHERE Countries.Name="Kazakhstan" AND (Languages.Name="German" OR Languages.Name="English") AND Guides.Guide_ID NOT IN 
(SELECT Guide_ID
    FROM GuidesUnavailableDates
    INNER JOIN GuidesUnavailableDates ON GuidesUnavailableDates.UnDate_G_ID=Guides_UnDate.UnDate_G_ID
    WHERE (Start_date<="21/06/2020" and End_date>="21/06/2020")
    OR (Start_date<="30/06/2020" and End_date>="30/06/2020")
    OR (Start_date>="21/06/2020" and End_date<="30/06/2020")
    )
;
```

Comment: `FROM Guides INNER JOIN Guides ON Guides_Countries.Guide_ID = Guides_Countries.Guide_ID`? Check the names of the tables.

Comment: Still have the same problem

Comment: `FROM Guides 
INNER JOIN Guides_Countries ON Guides.Guide_ID = Guides_Countries.Guide_ID`

Comment: Your code does not make sense because we don't know all about the tables that you use and the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple table names appearing multiple times in your `FROM` clauses.  That is causing your problem.  I think you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Guides g JOIN
     Guides_Countries gc
     ON gc.Guide_ID = g.Guide_ID JOIN
     Countries c
     ON c.Country_ID = gc.Country_ID JOIN
     Guides_Languages gl
     ON g.Guide_ID = gl.Guide_ID JOIN
     Languages l
     ON l.Language_ID = gl.Language_ID
WHERE c.Name = 'Kazakhstan' AND
      l.Name IN ('German', 'English') AND 
      g.Guide_ID NOT IN (SELECT gud.Guide_ID
                         FROM GuidesUnavailableDates gud
                         WHERE gud.Start_date <= '2020-06-30' AND
                               gud.End_date >= '2020-06-21'
                        );
```

Notes:

- `Guide_Countries` is not in your `FROM` list although `Guides` is there twice.
- `IN` is much simpler than mutiple `OR`s.
- All columns are qualified so it is clear what table they are coming from.
- All tables have simple table aliases which are abbreviations for the table names.
- There is no need for a `JOIN` in the subquery.
- Use well formatted dates.
- I am guessing that the weird date logic is to find an overlap with the time period mentioned so I simplified the logic.  (You haven't explained the logic, so this is a guess and your original code doesn't make sense.)
- I strongly recommend using `NOT EXISTS` with subqueries rather than `NOT IN`.  However, I did not change the code here (mostly because I can't really tell what the subquery is supposed to be doing).